# BindingSource - what are the advantages of using BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

What gives me using something like this:

```
DataGridView dgvDocuments = new DataGridView();
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
DataTable dtDocuments;

dtDocuments = MsSQL.GetDocuments(dtpOd.Value, dtpDo.Value);
bindingSource.DataSource = dtDocuments;
dgvDocuments.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

instead of this:

```
DataGridView dgvDocuments = new DataGridView();
DataTable dtDocuments;

dtDocuments = MsSQL.GetDocuments(dtpOd.Value, dtpDo.Value);
dgvDocuments.DataSource = dtDocuments;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`BindingSource` have many benefits, below some of them

1) When you bind data to any control with bindingsource it will take effect both sides. Any changes made to datasource effects to control and any change to control effects datasource. You don't need take value from control and assign to datasource again

2) You can apply `filter` to `datasource` with `bindingsource`

3) You can work with one `datasource` binded to `many controls`. For Example you have table `Fruits`, and you bind this `table` to `2 DataGridView` to show `Aplles` and `Peaches` seperately. With `bindingsource` `Filter` property you can show `Apples` and `Peaches` seperately.

4) You can do Searching, Sorting, Editing, Filtering with bindingsource

You can not see bindingsource benefit on basic lists, but there is more than basic list you will see how bindingsource is usefull.

You can get more informtaion [Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84476/data-binding-for-windows-forms/)

Comment: Note that for #1 to work, the model has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 5):

One of the advantages is that if you manipulate values in the DataGridView manually then the changes will be reflected in the underlying data.
(EDIT: apparently this also works with normal DataSource binding.)

another advantage is that you get the possibility to add an entry to the underlying data (at least if it is a `List`) by clicking on the extra empty field and edit the values. This will add a new item without any additional code for you to write.

[image]

This [Detailed Data Binding Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/24656/a-detailed-data-binding-tutorial) may help to shed more light on the capabilities of data binding in general

**EDIT:**

One more difference is that manipulation of the underlying data, like adding an item to a List will not be reflected in the `DataGridView` even if assigning the `DataSource` property again which would work for example in a `ComboBox`.
But a reassigning of a new instance of a `BindingSource` will do the trick.

So if you have a List of persons:

```
List<pers> list = new List<pers>();
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = perlist;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

and later on want to add a new item to the list in the code, just create a new instance of `BindingSource`, reassign it to the `DataGridView.DataSource`

```
list.Add(new pers());

bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = perlist;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

and the new item will be display

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something, but for me changes are reflected both ways even without `BindingSource`

Comment: @Slai you are right. I wonder what mistake I made last time when I tried and it did not work out. So I saved this in my brain as advantage, because I used `BindingSource` instead of normal binding and solved my problem.

Comment: a lot of tutorials and code samples use it, so to most it might seems like it is needed. Visual Studio creates BindingSource when data binding trough the Designer, so there might be some use of it that I am unaware of (maybe separating the filtering and sorting logic from the data source). `BindingSource` is needed when data binding some collections like `Dictionary`, but I don's see much use of it otherwise.